How can I separate plots from a bundle of plots?
Using this code, I generate a graph with hundreds of solutions to a PDE. However, I would like to see only 10, during the evolution of the wavefunction, 1-10, with equal intervals from start to end. How can I do that?
(* Define parameters *)
L = 10;                 (* Length of the domain *)
T = 2;                  (* Total time *)
dx = 0.1;              (* Spatial step size *)
dt = 0.005;            (* Time step size *)
xMax = L;              (* Maximum x value *)
xValues = Range[0, xMax, dx]; (* Spatial grid *)
mMax = Round[T/dt];    (* Maximum time index *)

(* Initialize wave function *)
ψ = Table[Exp[-(x - L/2)^2], {x, xValues}]; (* Initial condition *)

(* Define the time evolution function *)
timeEvolution[ψ_, m_] := Module[{ψNew, nonlinearTerm},
    ψNew = ψ;  (* Start with the current wave function *)
    (* Update wave function using FDM *)
    For[i = 2, i < Length[ψ] - 1, i++,
        nonlinearTerm = Abs[ψ[[i]]]^2 ψ[[i]];
        ψNew[[i]] = ψ[[i]] - (dt/(2 I)) ((ψ[[i + 1]] - 2 ψ[[i]] + ψ[[i - 1]])/(dx^2)) - dt nonlinearTerm;
    ];
    ψNew
];

(* Store results for plotting *)
results = {};
(* Time-stepping loop *)
For[m = 1, m <= mMax, m++,
    ψ = timeEvolution[ψ, m];
    AppendTo[results, Abs[ψ]^2];  (* Store wave function magnitude *)
];

(* Plot the results *)
ListLinePlot[results, PlotRange -> All, 
             PlotLabel -> "Wave Function Evolution", 
             AxesLabel -> {"x", "|ψ(x,t)|^2"}, 
             ImageSize -> Large]

Now consider this variant of the command with slight changes in the parameters.
(* Define parameters *)
L = 10;                 (* Length of the domain *)
T = 5;                  (* Total time *)
dx = 0.1;               (* Spatial step size *)
dt = 1;             (* Time step size *)
xMax = L;              (* Maximum x value *)
xValues = Range[0, xMax, dx]; (* Spatial grid *)
mMax = Round[T/dt];    (* Maximum time index *)
(* Initialize wave function *)
\[Psi] = Table[Exp[-(x - L/2)^2], {x, xValues}]; (* Initial condition *)
(* Define the time evolution function *)
timeEvolution[\[Psi]_, m_] := Module[{\[Psi]New, nonlinearTerm},
    \[Psi]New = \[Psi];  (* Start with the current wave function *)
    (* Update wave function using FDM *)
    For[i = 2, i < Length[\[Psi]] - 1, i++,
        nonlinearTerm = Abs[\[Psi][[i]]]^2 \[Psi][[i]];
        \[Psi]New[[i]] = \[Psi][[i]] - (dt/(2 I)) ((\[Psi][[i + 1]] - 2 \[Psi][[i]] + \[Psi][[i - 1]])/(dx^2)) - dt nonlinearTerm;
    ];
    \[Psi]New
];
(* Store results for animation *)
results = {};
(* Time-stepping loop *)
For[m = 1, m <= mMax, m++,
    \[Psi] = timeEvolution[\[Psi], m];
    AppendTo[results, Abs[\[Psi]]^2];  (* Store wave function magnitude *)
];
(* Create the animation *)
ListAnimate[Table[
  ListLinePlot[results[[m]], PlotRange -> All, 
               PlotLabel -> "Wave Function Evolution", 
               AxesLabel -> {"x", "|\[Psi](x,t)|^2"}, 
               PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, 
               ImageSize -> Large,
               PlotLegends -> {"t = " <> ToString[m dt]}],
  {m, 1, Length[results]}
]]

The output of this last command is given here, where you can clearly see how one wave evolves with the soliton growing and growing.

If you look at this function, it evolves over time clearly. While the first command shows only a bundle of functions. How can I show another rogue wave of the 200 solutions like in this simple image of 4 steps, showing its evolution over time?

I would like to see only 10 can you not just divide the number of rows by 10? You have 400 rows now in your result. Right? So you want only 10 frames? 1,40,80,120,160, etc... 400  if so you can try {row, col} = Dimensions[results]; res2 = results[[Range[1, row, Round[row/10]], All]]; and now use res2 in your Plot command in place of result  THis is what I get https://i.sstatic.net/oTGp5WYA.png

@Nasser thanks. But I will change the code.

@Nasser you can see that the same function is colored in the same way. If you sse the update in the post, you see what I mean

You may select every 20th data in "results" by: results[[1;;200;;20]]. With this:
ListLinePlot[results[[1 ;; 200 ;; 20]], PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Wave Function Evolution", 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "|\[Psi](x,t)|^2"}, ImageSize -> Large]



Thanks Daniel, the thing is that those solutions you show are related to the differential equation, but they are not related to one another as $\psi(x,1)$, $\psi(x,2)$, $\psi(x,3)$ and $\psi(x,n)$ over time viable t=1, 2, 3 ...n. Since time is on the x axis, we would like to show how at least one of them evolves. Is it possible to pick out on family of time-dependent solutions ,and show their evolution over time, in say, 10 steps - $\psi(x,1)...\psi(x,10)$? That was actually my intent from the start, but I got this bundle of solutions.

I do not understand what you mean. You have 200 numeric sequences in "results". And you want to see only 10, but 10 of what? I assumed you mean 10 of the sequences. Please describe you needs better.

I will add an update in the question.

I deaccepted the answer, just to arouse some more answers. In case no other answers arrive, I will reaccept yours!
